# How to do fields.property()?

Tags: python, odoo

I've a problem that concerned with fields.property().
When I changed 'Stock Input/Output Account' for related branch company, other branch data will loss in ir.property table.

I created my internal module with on_change function for that 'Stock Input/Output Account' field. When on_change function done... if related data is not have in the table, it'll save in the ir.property table.
But... when I clicked 'save' button, updated data (firstly save data) and added data will have in the table. But they'll use only updated data.. not used new added data. Why?

on_change function:

```
 def onChangeAcc(self,cr,uid,ids,aid,name,context=None):
            print "on chang acc......................"
            print("IDS",ids,"AID",aid,"name",name)
            if ids and aid:
                val_ref = 'account.account,'+str(aid)
                res_id = 'product.template,'+str(ids[0])
                company_id = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context).company_id.id
                cr.execute("SELECT id FROM ir_property WHERE name='"+name+"' AND value_reference='"+val_ref+"' AND res_id='"+res_id+"' AND company_id="+str(company_id))        
                result = cr.fetchall()
                if not result: 
                    print "if not result..................."
                    company_id = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context).company_id.id
                    fields_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.fields').search(cr, uid, [('name','=',name)])[0]
                    vals = {
                        'name':name,
                        'value_reference':val_ref,
                        'res_id':res_id,
                        'company_id':company_id,
                        'fields_id':fields_id,
                    } 
                    print("vals",vals)
                    self.pool.get('ir.property').create(cr,uid,vals,context)
```

If I need any configuration for multi company.. please, explain me.
I don't know any about of configuration. :(
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all property fields are not something that you should create on the fly as it effects whole system.

You can refer to this video for the configuration : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6M0ibLW3g&wadsworth=1

Comment: Thanks. I got it.. :)
I found a link and then I did some configuration for that case.